# Using USB port from c++

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, usb

i was just wondering if somebody could give me any pointers about how to use USB ports on Ubuntu(and other unix systems) &&/|| (and/or :]) windows. I was trying to googling some stuff up but i failed horribly. Even names of libraries to be used etc would be appriciated.

Thanks, Tomas Herman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use libusb for direct access to USB. http://www.libusb.org/

If you instead wish to use a USB serial port or other device for which the OS already has drivers, look for other means. E.g. /dev/input/event* or /dev/ttyUSB* devices on Linux.

Comment: One thing to note: libusb 1.0 and later is only supported for some Unixen; Mac OS X and Windows are not supported.  libusb 0.1 is cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

Two quick links for you:

http://www.linux-usb.org/ - The Linux USB project

http://www.libusb.org/ - "...the **libusb** project. It aims to create a library for use by user level applications to access USB devices regardless of OS."